# InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ' table '?

Tags: mysql-5.6, wamp

i have some project hosted by wampp server, which used to work without any issue.

this week , it can't serve anymore , examining  the mysql logs i got this lines:

```
2019-12-05 08:23:00 1464  InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
 2019-12-05 08:23:00 5320 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'wordpressdev/b2s_post_sched_settings'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
 2019-12-05 08:23:00 5320 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"wordpressdev"."b2s_post_sched_settings"', ignored.
```

how could i fix ?

## update

i figured out that , that error comes because i have moved out wordpressdev folder from mysql 's data directory.
after putting it back the errorb change to :

```
2019-12-06 08:44:04 8084 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-12-06 08:44:04 1fb4  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
2019-12-06 08:44:04 8084 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'wordpressdev/b2s_posts'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2019-12-06 08:44:04 8084 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"wordpressdev"."b2s_posts"', ignored.
```

by googling i found that i need to give the full access permission to the data folder for the users , i did that but the problem persist